# Sock puppet account suspicion

Tags: discussion

I suspect that a user **A** has two brand new accounts **B**  and **C** as of today, which he uses to upvote his own questions and answers.

Moreover, answers of low quality to questions of **A** are seemingly submitted from **B** and **C** and **accepted**.

I might be terribly wrong and this is just one big family devoted to chemistry, but I smell a rat.

Where can I submit the user IDs in question?

Maybe one of the mods can have a look at the logs then.

Comment: Ooooh community drama *rubs hands together*. I'll go grab some popcorn.

Comment: Hahaha, too late - for now ;-)

Comment: Well great... now what am I going to do with all this? (*stares at bowl of popcorn*)

Comment: Depends ;) Either put it in the freezer (*yuck*) and wait for the next crook or enjoy it right now with some beer (or coffee) and a copy of "The World's End".

Comment: Ah, beer.  My number one solution.

Comment: did someone say popcorn???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just flag one of their posts and put the details and any additional links there. Use multiple flags if you need more space.

Comment: As ManishEarth said, flags are definitely the way to go: these are confidential and will be reviewed by the moderators, so you can give any details about suspect activity while avoiding ad hominem…

Answer (score 3):

I noticed this behavior also and resisted bringing it up here. The voting and flagging mechanisms are the way to deal with this. We are free to downvote an accepted answer if it is subpar.